# A state or feeling of being ready to fill an obvious void

Tags: single-word-requests

Like when the teacher is talking and you already know the answer way before she finishes asking the question. You are in a state of ...

I'm trying to think of the word or words that best describe this state of mind. It's a state that I want to create as a teacher where I repeatedly give students more explicit examples of a concept over time, but I wait until the very end to point out the obvious concept that connects all those examples. I want the student to have a sense of anticipation and excitement that they already know what concept I'm referring to before I ever state it explicitly. I'm hoping this teaching exercise will build their confidence in the material. I just don't know the best term to use to describe this state of mind that I'm trying to induce in the student.

I have considered using the words `obvious` or `suspense` but I am looking for something a little more specific to the cognitive aspect of the meaning. It's almost something attune to a mental itch that you really, really want to scratch.

Comment: Perhaps a state of readiness or eagerness?

Comment: I like the word eagerness. That seems to capture it well.

Comment: I agree that "eagerness" is the word. That feeling is based on your students' recognition or identification of a concept that is already known.

Comment: The OP says "Like when the teacher is talking and you already know the answer way before she finishes asking the question. You are in a state of.."  I don't get how can this be *eagerness*?  Eagerness is close to *keenness* or *enthusiasm*. I think *anticipation* or *expectation* as answered by @Chris are better suited to the context presented by the OP. I get the OP wants to create *eagerness* among the pupils, by this method, but I don't think the term is *eagerness*.

Comment: Before you state it explicitly (as per your words), could you not call that _implicit understanding_?

Answer (score 1):

Anticipation
Expectation
Receptivity
Frustration
Hunger
?

In psychology terms, I think you are describing Jakk Panksepp's SEEKING, but that term doesn't work well except as jargon.

Answer (score 1):

You are in a [**Responsive**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/responsive) state.

> quick to respond or react appropriately or sympathetically

Comment: Does this not describe the nature of the student; rather than imply they already know the answer before the question is asked _in this particular case_?

Answer (score 1):

Anticipatory is the state of anticipating your opportunity. The joy of this  frequently disappears once the opportunity is acquired and the true conditions are understood.

Comment: Elliot, this answer would be better with a citation.

Answer (score 1):

***Alacrity*** describes this state of mind well.

When happily ready to give the answer...

"You are in a state of *alacrity*."

> ***alacrity***, noun:  ...cheerful readiness or willingness.
>   ([OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/4507?redirectedFrom=alacrity#eid))

Answer (score 1):

Not single words, but colloquially, you might be "*drooling with anticipation*" or "*chomping at the bit*"

The first might be how you feeling waiting for a great meal; the second is how a race horse might feel waiting at the gate.

Answer (score 0):

> Like when the teacher is talking and you already know the answer way before she finishes asking the question. You are in a state of ...

...[preparation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preparation).

*noun* : 2. a state of being [**prepared**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prepared)

*adj* : subjected to a special process or treatment

- They were well **prepared** and scored high on the test.

> **prepared** Synonyms: *fit, ready, set*
>
> Definition of **prepared** for English Language Learners:
>
> - made ready in advance
> - ready for something
> - in a suitable condition for some purpose or activity
> - willing to do something

Slang for **preparation**: [prep](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prepped).

> Painting a room involves a lot of **prep**.

- Like when the teacher is talking and you already know the answer way before she finishes asking the question. You are in a state of **preparation**. You are prepared, prepped.

*Merriam Webster*